# fancyhdr and \iftopfloat

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr, bounding-box

I am relatively new to LaTeX, and I have been using the `fancyhdr` package, in which I have chapter title and numbers with `headrulewidth` on top of the page. However, when I have figures on top of a page these interfer with the heading. I have tried the `\iftopfloat` command, but it does not seems to be recognizable in LaTeX (it says unrecognized command), while I don't receive any error messages when I compile. Does anyone have a suggestion to what I can do? I would preferably have the figures under the headings, i.e after the headrulewidth-line.

I have included a top figure. Yes when a figure is displayed on top of the page the figures interfers with the heading. As I mentioned I am new to LaTeX, so it might be something basic I don't understand.

Help is very much appreciated :)

### Illustration of the problem:

[image: image on top page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perhaps related to a problem with the image bounding box. An easy-way-out would be to add

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
```

to your document preamble. This `export`s the [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` command. Then, include your image using

```
\includegraphics[set height=1.1\height,<options>]{<image>}
```

Here `<options>` refers to any other settings you may have specified previous for this image (like `width=.8\linewidth`) and `<image>` is the name of the image you included. The idea using `set height=1.1\height` is to actually insert `<image>` using a 10% increase of the existing bounding box (or 110% of the current height). This *should* shift it down by 10%; maybe that would be enough to avoid the overlap with the header.

Here is an example showing the opposite - a reduction in the bounding box size by 50%. It's just meant to highlight what happens:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{An image}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[set height=.5\height,width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{An image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```